# How to model the kinematics of gases expelled from comets and planetary atmospheres?

Tags: atmosphere, planetary-science, radiation, comet

Once the ices of comets sublimate, where do they move to, and with which equations do you describe their motion in the interplanetary medium? Similarly, where do the gases that are stripped from the atmospheres of rocky planets go, and how do we model the interaction of these gas molecules? How is the interaction of these gas molecules with solar radiation modeled to predict their motion?

Comment: *Interesting question!* There are four votes to close as "needs more focus" because there are a lot of different topics that would need to be covered in an answer to address all of these questions. I think that if this question were migrated to Astronomy SE it's possible someone may still want to take on the whole thing at once, because these are so interrelated that you can't really answer one without answering the others. So I've voted to close in order to provide an opportunity for migration to Astronomy SE, but you'll have to flag for moderator assistance since it's not closed as off-topic

Comment: @uhoh I haven't noticed the close votes. Is there any direct way to migrate this question to Astronomy SE?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6wK3.png No but I think it will be closed soon and you can then flag for moderator assistance and ask them if they would consider doing it. You could also copy/paste the text to a new question there and then delete this copy here if you like without any problem, but it's considered "best form" to not generate a second copy and instead migrate. btw once you reach 500 reputation points (I think) then you'll be able to see the close votes. It's just how SE works it seems.

Comment: From [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/303080) see [What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587/303080)